How to place a v-tooltip inside a label in a v-text-field?
I am trying to put a v-tooltip inside a persistent label in a v-text-field but it is not functioning. The tooltip shows up next to the label but nothing happens when I hover my mouse over it, it should show the text "Test popup text" when hovering it. Small example: Link to vuetify playground.
I have tried to move around things, wrap it etc but nothing seem to work.
Questions

Can I have a tooltip inside my label like that and working?
How can I change my code to get it to work?


Not sure if that matters to you, but a tooltip on a label goes against Material Design, which Vuetify implements. It does not work with mobile either. My guess is that you want to add supporting text, which would go under the input (see hint prop).

Because the pointer-events of the input label is set as none by vuetify.
You can override it to make the elements in the label hoverable:
<style>
  .v-label.v-field-label.v-field-label--floating {
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
</style>

Playground

I think this is not possible due to the fact that this #label slot is not designed to handle interactivity: please check this https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/18270 ( there's also a workaround published here).
Hope this helps!!
